# Detect if an application is not in use

Tags: delphi

How can I detect if an application is not used for more than x minutes in DELPHI

Comment: do you want to do this inside the app itself or are you monitoring apps externally?  What is the nature of the app, or is this just a general question?  You need to define what "not used" means.  That may sound pedantic, but it really affects the nature of what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, sorry
It’s a management application. And I need to be able to detect if the user is not using it for more than x minutes, to be able to perform some “housekeeping” actions.
All from inside the application.

Comment: Minor suggestion: I don't have enough rep to edit your question title, but "a" should be "an"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the applications OnDeactivate and onActive events.. 
That way you can abort the longrunning job if the user activates your program again.

ex:

```
 Application.OnDeactivate = yourDeactivProcedure;

procedure mainform.YourDecativateProcedure (sender : tObject);
begin
 // do your job.. 
end;
```

To handle the activate event to abort you either have to do it a bad way with a sleep and after the sleep check if i global vairable has been set. 
Or you can have a theared object that does the loongrunning job. 
Which I would say is much better. You can set the loongrunningjobs priority to low and it wont affect your program as much,

Comment: What if the application is still active (has focus) but the user is away?

Answer (score 4):

If you write Windows app take a look at [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Very nice. All code I've seen (or have written) doing the tracking of user input was essentially doing what this one API call seems to do... It's really much better than hooking into mouse and keyboard handling of the Application object.

Comment: Any suggestions when you should check if the time expired? With a timer?

Comment: Oh, and this is session wide. It won't help if you wanted to know if *your* application is in use. If someone is using MSWord instead of while your application is open on the background this function will still return activity.

Comment: I don't know about the needs of the OP (his question is awfully vague), but I consider the fact that it is session-wide a plus for my use case. I don't want to log out the user just because he's for example reading the documentation of my program in a PDF viewer, I want to do that only if he's...

Comment: actually away from the system, doing something else entirely. This API function will work perfectly for me, I didn't actually know it yet. And you could actually parse the "if an application" instead of "if my application" as the OP wanting the same. Maybe he should edit the question.

Comment: Ok here goes: It’s a management application. And I need to be able to detect if the user is not using it for more than x minutes, to be able to perform some “housekeeping” actions. He can be using other application as long as ”my” application as not the focus.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that looks for mouse and keybord activity with the applicatin

```
procedure TUserActivity.AppMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := False;
  case Msg.message Of
    WM_KEYDOWN,
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
    WM_MBUTTONDOWN,
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
      Activity := TRUE;
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    begin
      if (LastXYPos <> Msg.lParam) then 
        Activity := True;
      LastXYPos := Msg.lParam;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you wanted to do something after a certain amount of inactivity you could reset a timer each time there is an activity.

Comment: I do something similar to this in my Delphi app to see when it was last used.  Works even with forms in COM libraries.  This approach means that the user can be busy in other apps but you can still detect that yours is not being used and, as you said, do some housekeeping, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Application.OnIdle](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/AppEvnts_TApplicationEvents_OnIdle.html) event:

Write an OnIdle event handler to perform special processing when an application is idle. An application is idle when it is not processing code. For example, an application is idle when it is waiting for input from the user.

OnIdle is called only once, as the application transitions into an idle state. It is not called continuously unless Done is set to false. Applications that set Done to false consume an inordinate amount of CPU time, which affects overall system performance.

Use either a timer or [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302%28VS.85%29.aspx) as @aku suggests in this event to determine if you can start your maintenance without interrupting the user

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're defining "used" -- if you were monitoring yourself, you could look at the last time you responded to user interaction by logging it when it happened (mouse move/key pressed/menu event fired/etc.). Monitoring another application is tricky as it'll be harder to define that it is "in use".

Comment: Yes
Just the user inside my application. I need to detect him not using the application for x minutes

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the application and what it does.  While users may not interact with it in the sense of new input, they certainly might be viewing the client area that is visible.

Also  - you don't say if you want to detect this internal to the app or external to the app.

Simple methods

- see if it has current focus.
- check if the window is visible

lots of others too, but they rely on the app itself.

You must define what you mean by "used" as well.  It could mean different things and that would make significant changes to how you determine whether it met your criteria or not.

Comment: I need to be able to detect if the user is not using it for more than x minutes, to be able to perform some “housekeeping” actions.